# vb.net multiple pictureBoxes, same width, maintain aspect ratio

Tags: vb.net, math, picturebox, aspect-ratio

I have a global variable called fWidth that is currently 300.

I'm setting **pictureBox.width = fWidth**, but then I want to do something like **pictureBox.height = calcImgHeight(originalHeight,originalWidth)**

This is where the problem comes in, because I'm terrible at math :D

```
Private Function calcImgHeight(oHeight, oWidth)
    Dim nHeight, ratio As Integer
    ratio = oWidth / fWidth
    nHeight = oHeight / ratio

    Return nHeight
End Function
```

What should the correct code be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet I'm worse at maths than you, but fortunately I'm good at Googling.

http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/

original height / original width x new width = new height

Comment: Easy peasy.  My google-fu is normally strong, but maybe not enough coffee yet. :|  Thanks